# Is there are reason why the float property should impact the functioning of a check box?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, checkbox, z-index

Is there are reason why the float property should impact the functioning of a check box?

I have the following Rails Form

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
<ul class="publications">
  <% @citations.each do |publication| %>
      <li>
        <div class = "PublicationCheckbox"><%= check_box_tag "publications[]", publication[:id] %></div>
        <div class = "PublicationString">
             <b><%= publication[:title] %></b>
             <%= publication[:authors] %>.
             <i><%= publication[:journal] %></i>,
             <%= publication[:year] %>,
             <%= publication[:volume] %>:
             <%= publication[:pages] %>
        </div>
      </li>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Add to profile" %>
  </div>

<%= link_to 'Show', @user %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', users_path %>

</ul>
<% end %>>
```

Here is the CSS

```
.publications {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;

    li {
        padding: 15px 0;
        border-top: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
        float: left;
       }

    .PublicationCheckbox{
        float: left;
       }

    .PublicationString {
        padding: 0px !important;
        padding-bottom: 10px !important;
        margin-left: 20px !important;
        float: left;
      }

      }
```

As it stands above, the checkboxes won't check. If I remove the float property from the the checkbox they work.

Comment: Have you tried to set the `float: left` property on the `checkbox` itself to see any difference?

Comment: Have a look in chrome inspector and see if another element is sitting on top of the checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the float property does not impact the functionality of a checkbox.  However, if you float a checkbox and another element near it has a higher z-index value with padding or margins sometimes you can get an invisible layer over the checkbox not allowing you to select it.

I would suggest that you inspect the checkbox with Chrome Dev Tools and see if anything is on top of the checkbox.  You may need to adjust the z-index of the checkbox so that it's on the upper most layer.

Comment: The checkbox is visible.....it just won't check when the float property is applied to the holding div

Comment: Yes, the checkbox is visible, but is there an invisible layer on top of it?